# Changing text occurs instant in width for element

Tags: html, css

So I'm attempting to make an "over time" text changer which changes a word in a sentence each few seconds, that code runs fine thou when the text is actually changed, the width of the sentence changes instantly removing the smoothness from the website.

Structure:

```
<div id="big">
  This is some <span id="change">text</span>
</div>
```

The word changing is `#change`. I've tried using **CSS transitions** for width as well as **transition properties**:

```
margin-top:   18%;
font-size:    70px;
font-family: 'Slabia 27px', 'Droid Serif', Arial;
>> text-align:   center;
text-transform: uppercase;

>> -webkit-transition-property: width;
>> -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
>> transition: width .8s ease;
```

**Also my jQuery (calls `APP.init()`)**:

```
var APP = {
  init: function() {
    loopChangeWord = setInterval(function(){
      var $change = $('#change');
      var iteration = ['quick', 'efficiently', 'well', 'together'];
      var current   = $change.html();
      for (var i = 0; i < iteration.length; i++) {
        if (iteration[i] == current) {
          if (i+1 > iteration.length-1) var nw = iteration[0];
          else nw = iteration[i+1];
          $change.fadeOut(500, function(){
            $change.html(nw).fadeIn(500);
          });
        }
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
};
```

In the end** I'm asking for a way for a smooth transition of the text being changed, I expected the width change would trigger the CSS animation thou was wrong!

Comment: post you jquery as well

Comment: done kind sir @AlaaMh

Comment: Have you tried transition `all` instead of transition `width`?

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the **text** value which is in your `<span id="change">text</span>` to match either one value of your `var iteration = ['quick', 'efficiently', 'well', 'together'];` array.

**Here is the working demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/5p36n34j/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: my upvote for you! sometimes it's simple but you need to focus as you did, great job dude!

Comment: @AlaaMh Thanks mate!

Comment: isn't all of the jsfiddle code the same? change the font size of the text and the issue arises again which is what I'm trying to fix :P

Comment: @Jek Yes. The jsfiddle and the code that you had posted are the same. I have tried changin the `font-size` attribute `#big` class (to both high/low values) and there is nothing breaking. All seems to work fine in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the help thou @DavidR, even though I didn't end up fixing my problem I achieved a better understanding of font sizes. I just moved on to a new look on the site :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `transition: all .8s ease;` on `#change` instead of `transition: width .8s ease;` on `#big`.

```js
var fontSize = 10;
$('#big').click(function() { 
 fontSize = fontSize * 2.2;
  $('#change').css('fontSize', fontSize + 'px');
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#big {
  margin-top: 18%;
  font-family: 'Slabia 27px', 'Droid Serif', Arial;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#change {
  transition: all .8s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big">
  Click on this <span id="change">text</span>
</div>
```